Why does voltage swing wildly on PAM8610?
I'm venturing into electronics and know relatively little.
I bought a PAM8610 and have built it out as circled below. I have a 12V, 5A power supply that is feeding directly into the PAM8610 via the blue wires shown in the picture.

The wires run from power supply, into the two blue wires, into this setup:

where I am doing the measuring, and then that runs into the PAM8610. What I've noticed though is that the voltage just swings wildly from 0 up to 400 some odd mV and then back to zero and the amp never actually doing anything whereas if I plug the power supply directly into the PAM8610, it starts and I get a red light.
I assume there must be a problem with the wires not being able to carry the current/voltage? I don't fully understand what the problem is though.

There is absolutely no way anyone can follow that rat's nest of wires in your photos!

That's why I described it in words

If red wire with red crocodile clip is positive from power supply, you are feeding positive supply into negative/black input of the snap-on battery terminal.
Simply put, you are powering it with wires wired incorretly for wrong polarity.

Justme has raised a good point. Please check if there has been a reverse polarity issue. The voltage swing also indicates that the connection between the power supply and the PAM8610 may be poor or unstable. It can be due to loose connections. The crocodile clips may not be able to provide a secure connection. Avoid using too many alligator clips in the power line if possible; they can introduce resistance and intermittent connections. If you also plan to make a  PAM8610 by yourself, here is a design that you can follow: https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/PAM8610TR_Dual_channel_power_amplifier_board.html

The voltage swinging indicates the supply senses a short circuit from the reversed chip after starting and shuts down, repeatedly starting and shutting down. It may simply be shorted via other routes as well if positive wire is connected to ground wire on module, via other connections.
